# How to add alternative key combinations for typing numbers

Tags: linux, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

My laptop's keyboard recently broke and the number keys no longer work. I still have to use it for a couple weeks, so I need a temporary solution.

It run Debian 11 with Gnome and Wayland.

I thought I could create key combinations so that every number is mapped to <kbd>AltGr</kbd> + the letter below it. That is,

<kbd>AltGr</kbd> + <kbd>Q</kbd> --> `1`

<kbd>AltGr</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd> --> `2`

And so on. I would also like to map the symbols that you obtain while pressing shift:

<kbd>AltGr</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Q</kbd> --> `!`

I tried modifiyng the XKB layout file, but I don't know how to get started.

Can someone explain me what do I need to add to the XKB file, or propose another solution?

Comment: Honestly, using an on-screen keyboard is a lot simpler, needs no initial setup and provides a much faster usage than the convoluted "solution" you're looking for.

Comment: I need to type a lot of numbers and I almost never use the touchpad. The on-screen keyboard is impractical for my workflow.

Comment: Plug in a borrowed USB keyboard, or buy one for as little as US$5.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik , I am already doing that. But I would prefer to avoid carrying a keyboard around.

Comment: Replacement internal keyboards can be found for ~US$10 for some laptops. Recently, I replaced one on an old HP 2000. The total work involved removing two screws, separating the case halves with a plastic wedge, unplugging the old keyboard, and putting things together -- a 10 minute task.